# How to remove io.socket namespace events?

Tags: node.js, events, namespaces

How can I simply remove an io.socket namespace?

```
 delete io.nsps['/my_namespace'];
```

This doesn't prevent firering events from existing connected clients.

OK to point 1)

```
 nsp= io.of('/my_namespace');
 nsp.removeAllListeners("my_event"); //this doesnt' work
```

2.) Of course I could make an if statement for this,but I think this is not a
clean solution.

3.)I don't know how to do this with a namespace without closing the complete socket(not just the namespace)) for the user.

My problem is,when I close a chat and delete all saving arrays and stuff, I get an error because events can still be fired(access on now undefined arrays,of course I could check if they exists but it was easier to just prevent events),like a send- or a disconnect- event.I don't want to prevent this on client-side,because of security issues.

Comment: What do you mean "remove a namespace"?  Do you mean to close all sockets that are currently connected to a particular namespace?  Or do you mean to refuse future connections to a particular namespace?  A namespace is a thing that sockets connect to and your server listens for connections to that namespace in order to do something particular to that namespace.  There's not really any more to it than that.  It's not like its a big resource thing or anything like that.

Comment: i simply want that no events can be fired. like nsp.on('connection',function(socket){socket.on('some_event',function(){//this code musn't run})});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not very clear what you're really trying to do.  To stop getting incoming socket events, you have a number of options:

1. Remove all your socket event handlers.
2. Set a flag that your event handling code checks and if the flag is set, it skips its normal code execution.
3. Disconnect all clients on that namespace and refuse new connections.

As always, if you tell us what problem you're really trying to solve rather than just asking about the solution you're trying to implement, we may be able to offer much better answers.  See a [description of the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for discussion about why it may be better to ask about your actual problem rather than asking about issues with your attempted solution.

Comment: finally i decided to choose option 2, but i still wonder why there isn't an .off event or a possibility to stop all events of a namespace.